# Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null (React Hook Form)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form with MUI and I'm getting this type of message quite often:

[image]

Now, I would be able to solve the problem, since I know what it is about, but does anyone know how I can know exactly which line in my code is causing it?

The picture shows only a few (I'm actually getting many more), but I'm going crazy trying to find the actual line that's causing the issue.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code.  To hunt it down, I'd first click the link in the warning and see if it gives you any clues.  That's a long shot.  Second, I would start by removing code until you find which line is causing the warnings.

Knowledge of MUI can help a bit.  There are several components that use the html input field such as `TextField`.  Basically, any component with the `inputProps` property (lowercase `inputProps`, not uppercase `InputProps`.  If you use any of these components, I'd start there.

Comment: Thank you. It's funny that they don't tell you exactly where the problem is. I will try to follow your advice.